# How to set an input box to the full width of the ui-grid cell?

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid

In an editable ui-grid v3.1.0, the input box does not fill the cell after the column has been resized by the user (see image).

[image]

I've tried modifying some css as follows, but the width was not affected:

```
.ui-grid-cell input[type='text']{
    background-color:pink;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: What's the styling of `.ui-grid-cell` and its cascading styles? Without a fuller demo of what you have, I can only suggest setting `display: block` on the input...

Comment: I tried display:block; -- did not adjust the width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found setting `min-width:100%;`causes the input box width to fill the containing cell.

```
.ui-grid-cell input[type='text']{
    min-width:100%;
}
```